# The tangent line to the curve of intersection of the surface $x^2+y^2=z$ and the plane $x+z=3$ at the point $(1,1,2)$ passes through

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, tangent-line

The tangent line to the curve of intersection of the surface $x^2+y^2=z$ and the plane $x+z=3$ at the point $(1,1,2)$ passes through

(A)$(-1,-2,4)$

(B)$(-1,4,4)$

(C)$(3,4,4)$

(D)$(-1,4,0)$

I can find the equation of the tangent line, If I can find the suitable parametrization($\vec{R(t)}$) using the equation $w(\lambda)=\vec{R(t)}|_{(1,1,2)}+ R'(t)|_{(1,1,2)}\lambda$

I made a parametrization by choosing $x=t,z=3-t,y^2=t-t^2.$ But it is not differnetiable at that point. How do I find the suitable parametrization?

Comment: Write the equations about the point $(1,1,2)$: $(z-2)=(y-1)^2+2(y-1)+(x-1)^2+2(x-1)$,$(x-1)+(z-2)=0$ and drop the quadratic terms: $(z-2)=2(y-1)+2(x-1),$ $(x-1)+(z-2)=0.$ Now you have the tangent line given as the intersection of the two tangent planes. (B) is on both.

Comment: Why do you need a parameterization of the intersection curve if you can already find an equation of the tangent line? Just see which of the four points satisfy that equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two surfaces, paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ and plane $z=3-x$, intersect on ellipse:
$$x^2+y^2=3-x \iff x^2+x+y^2=3 \iff (x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}+y^2 = 3 \iff (x+\frac{1}{2})^2+y^2=\frac{13}{4} \\$$

$$\iff \frac{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2}{\frac{13}{4}}+\frac{y^2}{\frac{13}{4}}=1$$

Now the tangent on the intersection curve at the point $P=(1,1,2)$ is easy to find, as well as it is easy to check which one of 4 points lie on this tangent...

Figure.
[image]

Comment: You do find the cylinder which intersects either of the two old equations in the ellipse. The eccentricity of the circle this cylinder projects to in the $xy$-plane is of course $0,$ but the eccentricity of the ellipse in the question is $\frac1{\sqrt{2}}.$

Comment: Putting the preceding comment differently, the way you’ve worded your answer suggests that the equation that you derived is that of the intersection curve, but it’s not. It’s either the equation of its projection onto the $x$-$y$ plane or the equation of a cylinder that passes through the actual intersection curve.

Comment: I accept both comments...

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2-z$ and $g(x,y,z) = x+z-3$.  Then $P=(1,1,2)$ lies on the intersection of the surfaces $S_1 = \{f=0\}$ and $S_2 = \{g=0\}$.

The tangent plane to $S_1$ at $P$ is normal to $\mathbf{n}_1 = \nabla f(P) = (2,2,-1)$.  The tangent plane to $S_2$ at $P$ is normal to $\mathbf{n}_2 = \nabla g(P) = (1,0,-1)$. 
 The line $L$ through $P$ tangent to $S_1 \cap S_2$ is the intersection of the two tangent planes.  That is, $L$ passes through $P$ in the direction $\mathbf{n}_1 \times \mathbf{n}_2$.

This is enough information to parametrize $L$ and decide which of the four points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ lie on it.  A quicker strategy may be to find the four vectors $\overrightarrow{PA}$, $\overrightarrow{PB}$, $\overrightarrow{PC}$, and $\overrightarrow{PD}$, and check with the dot product which are perpendicular to both $\mathbf{n}_1$ and $\mathbf{n}_2$.
\begin{align*}
    \overrightarrow{PA} &= (-2,-3,-6) \\
    \overrightarrow{PB} &= (-2,3,2) \\
    \overrightarrow{PC} &= (2,3,2) \\
    \overrightarrow{PD} &= (-2,-3,-2) \\
\end{align*}
We see that only $\overrightarrow{PB}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{n}_2$. So assuming the correct answer is listed, it would have to be B.

As a further check, we see that $\overrightarrow{PB}$ is perpendicular to $\mathbf{n}_1$.  In fact, $\mathbf{n}_1 \times \mathbf{n}_2 = (2,-3,-2) = - \overrightarrow{PB}$.